# Интегралы в c++, qt

Tags: c++, qt, математика

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно в C++ решить двойной интеграл, где к тому же есть мнимая единица. Например такой:  [image: Интеграл]

Comment: точно также, как и без мнимых единиц. точно так-же как и одинарный интеграл.

Comment: В данном случае двойной интеграл можно заменить на произведение интегралов. (Внутри произведение множителей зависящих от fi и teta по отдельности.) Вас должна была смутить неопределенность в точке fi=pi/2 .

Comment: Вам численно или символьно?

Comment: Численно, чтоб значение получилось

Answer (score 3):

Нижний интеграл состоит из произведения двух независимых частей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первом интеграле все просто, кроме того, что есть точки типа деления 0/0, и просто надо найти соответствующие пределы (это просто) и подставить. А там - хоть Симпсона натравите :)

Во втором все тоже просто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Совершенно очевидно, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(попробуйте набросать график подынтегральной функции), так что все, что вам надо - вычислить обычный определенный интеграл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что численно даже проще, чем первый интеграл...

Надеюсь, писать код для интегрирования одним из множества детальнейшим образом расписанных в учебниках методов не требуется?

Намекаю: посмотрите на график первой функции и прикиньте, чему равен первый интеграл...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]